# Rails 3.2.3 load javascript from public folder before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Is there any way to load JavaScript from `public` folder before JavaScript-files from `assets/javascript`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use the classic `javascript_include_tag` in your layout.

Given I have a file `in_public.js` in my public folder.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/in_public" %>
```

Comment: The initial forward slash in the path is key! Otherwise it still links to a subdirectory of /assets.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just add

```
//= require_tree public
```

in the top of the file before

```
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: This will concatenate *all* javascript files in the public directory without any particular order, which could cause lots of issues. Furthermore, I'm not sure this'll work without adding Rails root to the list of paths sprockets uses to find assets to precompile.

Answer (score 0):

**It automatically includes all the .js from public directory..**
 just make sure you have //= require_tree . in application.js (rails do it itself)